# How to Modify Code Runner's Default Command Line to Include g++ -std=c++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-code

I recently tried running some code on VS Code but, as I'm using C++11 Standard code, I have to manually change the execution code in terminal to `g++ -std=c++11` to actually run the code without errors.

I'm using **Code Runner v0.11.8 by Jun Han**

How can I set this option as the default?

Answer (score 1):

Follow below steps:

- Open VsCode settings using **CTRL+,** or from left bottom side
- click edit `settings.json`
- add the following code snippet in the end:

  ```
   {
     "code-runner.executorMap": {
         "cpp": "cd $dir && g++ -std=c++11 $fileName -o .\\$fileNameWithoutExt && $dir$fileNameWithoutExt"
      }
   }
  ```

& it's done.

**NOTE:** Make sure VsCode terminal profile is *Command prompt*.

**My setup:**

- I use this execution command, it also remove **.exe** file after execution of the program:

  ```
    "code-runner.executorMap": {

  // -lm flag for linking c file with libm (will enable use of math.h in VsCode)
      "c": "cd $dir && gcc $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt.exe -lm && .\\$dir$fileNameWithoutExt.exe && del $dir$fileNameWithoutExt.exe ",
      "cpp":"cd $dir && g++ -std=c++17 $fileName -o $fileNameWithoutExt.exe && .\\$fileNameWithoutExt.exe && del $dir$fileNameWithoutExt.exe",

  },
  ```

You can use any version like **-std=c++14** or **-std=c++17**.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

On this [page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) there is a Configuration section in which you have example how to specify compilation for c language. Write your own for C++ with flags you need and I think that it will be enough.